# Why does setting the opacity cause div to overlay lower divs in DOM / page?

Tags: html, css

When I set .header's opacity to something less than one, it overlays the image in .banner, but when I set .header's opacity to one or don't set it at all, the image in .banner overlays .header.  Why?

```
<div>
  <div>      
   <div class="header">
   </div>

   <div class="subHeader">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div>
   <div>
    <img class="banner" src="./images/foo.jpg" />
   </div>

   <div class="footer">
   </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: #cbd8e4;
    height: 70px;
}

.subHeader {
    background-color: #007934;
    height: 35px;
    opacity: .4;
}

.banner {
    width: 1180px;
    margin-top: -105px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #007934;
    height: 40px;
}
```

as opposed to:

```
.header {
    background-color: #cbd8e4;
    height: 70px;
    opacity: .9; /*this displays over the image in .banner */
}
```

Comment: It's because the display context has layered your image below the header. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fCm5s/ Note how I set `position: relative` and `z-index` on `.banner`, so it "layers" higher in the order.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the opacity to anything other than 1 changes the element's `z-index`.

[MDN explores this a bit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

If it's a problem, you could try using ...

```
filter: alpha(opacity=x);
```

or

```
background-color: rgba(r, g, b, a);
```

... but the latter only changes the opacity of the background.

Comment: Now that I look into it filter doesn't work for all browsers, so don't try using that.